# Refresh datatables data from values from array list

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have 2 HTML in which I'm just loading data with json then applying jquery datables on them. What I need now is to refresh the data but with new parameters.

example.

```
  JSON:
    [
    {"name":"jon","sales":"100","set":"SET1"},
    {"name":"charlie","sales":"500","set":"SET1"},
    {"name":"jon","sales":"350","set":"SET2"},
    {"name":"charlie","sales":"300","set":"SET2"}]

    <table id="SET1" class="display compact">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Sales</th>
    </table>
    <table id="SET2" class="display compact">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Sales</th>
    </table>

    JS:

     var uri = 'api/schedules';
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //function to refresh data 
                //loop thru every dept and query new data. 
                (function () {
                    var departments = ['Accounting', 'Sales', 'Marketing']
                    var idx = 0;
                    var len = departments.length;
                    function doNext() {

                        var entry = departments[idx];
                        console.log(idx + ":" + entry);
                        GetData(entry)
                        idx++;
                        if (idx < len) {
                            // Don't do anything special
                        } else {
                            // Reset the counter
                            idx = 0;
                        }
                        setTimeout(doNext, 10000);
                    }
                    doNext();
                }());//end of function
            }); //End Jquery Ready


        function GetData(dept) {
                $.getJSON(uri, { department: dept })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                        var tr;
                        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                            tr.append("<td >" + item.NAME + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + item.SALES+ "</td>");
                            tr.append("</tr>");
//loading the data to respective table set
                            $("#" + item.SET).append(tr);

                        });
          })
            }
```

The function to load the data works. I can see the new data every minute. Initializing the datatables works when is just ran manually.

But if I call the GetData(dept) only the first 'Department' gets loaded. at the second department I get errors from datatable that it can't load the data to the table.

I tried clearing the table with table.empty() aldo table.destroy() and redraw 
but I have not been able to make it work.

How do I refresh and redraw the data on the datatables?

Comment: Whats wrong with my destroy method? It's perfectly work in my case

Comment: 1. If you are using jQuery dataTables, where and then are you initialising those tables? 2. Why are you using both `$(document).ready()` and `(function()` redundantly? There is no reason for anyone of them. 3. Why are you inserting new rows by jQuery?

Comment: @davidkonrad, you are correct. I made a mistake with the both .ready. The reason why I'm adding the row with Jquery was because I want to split the rows to 2 tables based on one of the cells values. I could not figure out how to do with the datables. 

I forgot to add when I'm initializing the datatables. But i'm initializing in the .done function from the ajax call. like table = $("table.display").Datatables({....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're not using DataTables to add your data. Rather, you're adding rows manually, and that is inefficient and means DataTables won't know about them, so sorting, searching etc. won't work as expected. Rather than do that use `rows.add()`. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/z4rb69rb/) seems to be doing what you need, though I'm having to fake the ajax, so you'll need to put the proper `getJSON()` back in:

```
let columns = [{
    "title": "Name",
    "data": "name"
}, {
    "title": "Sales",
    "data": "sales"
}];

let SET1 = $("#SET1").DataTable({
    "columns": columns
});
let SET2 = $("#SET2").DataTable({
    "columns": columns
});

let response = [{
    "name": "jon",
    "sales": "100",
    "set": "SET1"
}, {
    "name": "charlie",
    "sales": "500",
    "set": "SET1"
}, {
    "name": "jon",
    "sales": "350",
    "set": "SET2"
}, {
    "name": "charlie",
    "sales": "300",
    "set": "SET2"
}];

let GetData = (dept) => {
    $.ajax({
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "json",
        "url": "/echo/json/",
        "data": {
            "json": JSON.stringify(response)
        },
        "success": (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            SET1.clear().rows.add(data.filter(x => x.set === "SET1")).draw();
            SET2.clear().rows.add(data.filter(x => x.set === "SET2")).draw();

        }
    });
}

let departments = [
    'Accounting',
    'Sales',
    'Marketing'
];
let idx = 0;

let doNext = () => {
    let entry = departments[idx];
    console.log(idx + ":" + entry);
    GetData(entry)
    idx++;
    if (idx === (departments.length)) {
        idx = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(doNext, 10000);
}
doNext();
```

Also, your HTML table creation can be simplified:

```
<table id="SET1" class="display compact"></table>
<table id="SET2" class="display compact"></table>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is great. I never seen lambda expression on Javascript.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @causita It's not a lambda expression - they're called [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)